# How can i modify 'mailbox features' on an Exchange user programatically?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

So what i really need to be able to do is disable Webmail and ActiveSync 'mailbox features' on specific users in Microsoft Exchange. I've looked into powershell script for it but i'm not really familiar with PS so i'd prefer to not use it if at all possible.

I can access the server and mail specifically using ExchangeService and EWS

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");

        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,new ItemView(10));

        foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
        }
```

However i cant figure out how to find the mailbox features. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found this somewhere on the interwebs I don't actually recall where. I just modified it to serve my purpose.

```
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig);
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        string serverFqdn = "server";
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(string.Format("$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://{0}/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos", serverFqdn));
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-PSSession $Session");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-CASMailbox -Identity '" + userID + "' -OWAEnabled $true");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Set-CASMailbox -Identity '" + userID + "' -ActiveSyncEnabled  $true");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();

        if (pipeline.Error != null && pipeline.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            // failed
        }
        else
        {
            // Success
        }

        runspace.Dispose();
        pipeline.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Exchange do you have? Features you're talking about not really "mailbox features" but transport settings and all PowerShell cmdlets are running against CAS servers

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity "John Smith" -OWAEnabled $false;
Set-CASMailbox -Identity "John Smith" -ActiveSyncEnabled $false;
```

/Yevgeny

Comment: when i attempt to execute that command in powershelll i just a a set-casmailbox is not a recognized name of a cmdlet. i'm not running this from the exchange server its self. our version is 2010

Comment: It should work in Exchange 2010 either. Do you run it Exchange Management Shell (it is PowerShell console with pre-loaded Exchange features)? If you're running PowerShell cmdlets from the local machine and you don't have Exchange Admin Tools installed, then this error is logical consequence of that. So, you can install them or run these cmdlets from Exchange server directly.